# React Native + Android: transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, react-native

I followed the instructions very carefully at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html to set up an Android AVD envrioment for my React Native project. I get this error when I run `react-native run-android` on my existing project:

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzble;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzble;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

I am able to run a fresh `react-native init AwesomeProject` just fine so I assume its something with my existing project and its dependancies. I know [Firestack](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack) for Firebase could be the culprit since it made some changes to the `build.gradle` files. I searched StackOverflow and Google and tried many of the sugestions. None worked. I gather from my reading that there may something in my `build.gradle` files that could be the cause so I am posting them as well.

root [build.grade](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivdj74cwi3yid6r/build.gradle?dl=0)

app [build.gradle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bosv42mx9eqqksg/build.gradle%202?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that you likely have two different libraries both pulling `com.google.android.gms`, so you can try just excluding it for `react-native-firestack`.

```
compile (project(':react-native-firestack')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Comment: That did cause the build process to compleate but the app crashed on the emulator right away. Stacktrace: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xb4q1iot5aj6fzo/stacktrace.txt?dl=0